# Find and Replace a Column in CSV1 based on CSV2 in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying replace the values of column "Close" in the first CSV with the values of column "LTP" in the second CSV where the following columns should be same in CSV2 and CSV1:

"Symbol=SYMBOL", "Date=TIMESTAMP", "Expiry=EXPIRY_DT", "Option Type=OPTION_TYP", "Strike Price=STRIKE_PR"

Here is the current structure of CSV1:

```
INSTRUMENT  SYMBOL  EXPIRY_DT   STRIKE_PR   OPTION_TYP  OPEN    HIGH    LOW CLOSE   SETTLE_PR   CONTRACTS   VAL_INLAKH  OPEN_INT    CHG_IN_OI   TIMESTAMP
OPTSTK  INFY    26-Apr-18   780 CE  0   0   0   408.6   361.05  0   0   0   0   2-Apr-18
OPTSTK  INFY    26-Apr-18   800 CE  0   0   0   388.95  341.15  0   0   0   0   2-Apr-18
OPTSTK  INFY    26-Apr-18   820 CE  0   0   0   369.35  321.25  0   0   0   0   2-Apr-18
OPTSTK  INFY    26-Apr-18   840 CE  0   0   0   349.75  301.35  0   0   0   0   2-Apr-18
OPTSTK  INFY    26-Apr-18   860 CE  0   0   0   330.2   281.45  0   0   0   0   2-Apr-18
OPTSTK  INFY    26-Apr-18   880 CE  0   0   0   310.75  261.55  0   0   0   0   2-Apr-18
OPTSTK  INFY    26-Apr-18   900 CE  0   0   0   291.35  241.65  0   0   0   0   2-Apr-18
OPTSTK  INFY    26-Apr-18   920 CE  0   0   0   272.15  221.75  0   0   0   0   2-Apr-18
OPTSTK  INFY    26-Apr-18   940 CE  0   0   0   216 201.85  0   0   5400    0   2-Apr-18
OPTSTK  INFY    26-Apr-18   960 CE  0   0   0   234.45  181.95  0   0   0   0   2-Apr-18
OPTSTK  INFY    26-Apr-18   980 CE  0   0   0   216.1   162.1   0   0   0   0   2-Apr-18
OPTSTK  INFY    26-Apr-18   1000    CE  0   0   0   136 142.3   0   0   24600   0   2-Apr-18
```

And the structure of CSV2 is:

```
Symbol   Date    Expiry  Option Type     Strike Price    Open    High    Low     Close   LTP     Settle Price    No. of contracts    Turnover in Lacs    Premium Turnover in Lacs    Open Int    Change in OI    Underlying Value
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  780 0   0   0   408.6   0   361.05  0   0   0   0   0   1137.15
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  1380    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   8.29    0.01    600 600 1137.15
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  820 0   0   0   369.35  0   321.25  0   0   0   0   0   1137.15
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  840 0   0   0   349.75  0   301.35  0   0   0   0   0   1137.15
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  860 0   0   0   330.2   0   281.45  0   0   0   0   0   1137.15
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  880 0   0   0   310.75  0   261.55  0   0   0   0   0   1137.15
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  900 0   0   0   291.35  0   241.65  0   0   0   0   0   1137.15
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  920 0   0   0   272.15  0   221.75  0   0   0   0   0   1137.15
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  940 0   0   0   216 216 201.85  0   0   0   5400    0   1137.15
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  960 0   0   0   234.45  0   181.95  0   0   0   0   0   1137.15
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  980 0   0   0   216.1   0   162.1   0   0   0   0   0   1137.15
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  1000    0   0   0   136 134 142.3   0   0   0   24600   0   1137.15
INFY    2-Apr-18    26-Apr-18   CE  1020    0   0   0   126 126 122.65  0   0   0   1200    0   1137.15
```

Comment: Have you had a look at [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) which will output an array? The task is fairly straight forward after that. Would be nice to see what you have tried.

Comment: But I am not sure if that would work because the number of rows in both the CSVs are not the same and not even sorted. That is why the I am trying to implement the column name comparison criteria.

Comment: It it was me I would insert one of the CSV in a database table, then loop over the other do my searching in the DB and write the new file.

Comment: "not sure" implies you have not tried. How about you think about the problem, work out what is required and what are the key points in each CSV (array after using `fgetcsv`) that are needed in the final modified array.

Comment: @Tigger I am at the same time thinking of the logic as well. But I am not well versed with PHP so it is tough

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix USing DB will be very time consuming since I have over 300 of each of these files and have more than 15k rows in CSV1 for each file.

Comment: @RustyBanks : If this is a one-off merge of a large selection of files it may be quicker to write a shell script (Linux, *BSD, OSX) using tools like `awk`. The [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) sister site could help you there if needed.

Comment: only 15k rows, relatively speaking that's nothing, I've done files with 1million + rows.  I don't know what you mean by time consuming, mysql can insert about 1k rows a second with enough ram. ( I'm spoiled with 56GB though)

Comment: If you are going to do them in memory, as in load one file in an array, then loop over the other and search through the array for the matching row, you should use md5 to hash those fields as the key (if there i no duplicate rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things about CSV and in general any file

> I am trying replace the values of column "Close" in the first CSV with the values of column "LTP" in the second CSV where the following columns.

You cannot "replace" anything in the file.  You can however pull the data from a file using `fgetcsv` then change it and write a new file with the changed data using `fputcsv`.

As you have shown "no code", I won't bother writing much.  But I will just go over the process.

1. read in the file (completely) with the new values in it, creating an array from it
2. read in the file you wish to change row by row
3. for each row of the second file, find the correct row in the first one (array) and update the data for that line in file #2 (your file #1)
4. write a new file that contains the updated data.
5. you have to read the file you want to change the data in last, because you want to preserve the order of the rows in that file, and well it's just easier that way.

A tip for matching the data.  When you read in file #1 take the fields you need to match and hash them using md5. Md5 is really fast on the order of something like 5 million hashes a second (yes I timed it)

```
$time = microtime(true);

for($i=0; $i <= 5000000; ++$i){
    md5("hello world");
}

echo "Complete :".number_format((microtime(true) - $time), 4);
```

Try it [yourself](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/210cba171fdd41dcb67621d2155e9c510db740a2)

Output

```
Complete :1.3057
```

Now this has nothing to do with security or anything else, I will explain in a second.

When you build you array (Step 1) take the fields you want to match and hash them and use that for the key in your array.

```
  $hash = md5(
      $row['Symbol'] .
      strtotime($row['Date']) . //convert to timestamp
      $row['Expiry'] .
      $row['Option Typ'] .
      $row['Strike Price']
  );

  $data[$hash] = $row;
```

Then do the same when you read in the second file (the file you want to modify)

```
 $newHash = md5(
      $row['SYMBOL'] .
      TIMESTAMP . //convert to timestamp
      $row['EXPIRY_DT'] .
      $row['OPTION_TYP'] .
      $row['STRIKE_PR'] .
  );
```

Then simply look up the hash in the `$data` array  `isset($data[$newHash])` as yo go through the file you are modifying.  Once you find the row with that data you need the rest is pretty trivial.

Now the basic way to read a file is

```
  $h = fopen('filename.csv', 'r');
  $data = [];

  $headers = false;
  while(!feof($h)){
      $row = fgetcsv($h);
      if(!$headers) $headers = $row;

      $row = array_combine($headers, $row);
      //do the hash "and other stuff" 
      $data[$hash] = $row;
  }
```

Then read the other file after that one is done, with the same kind of loop, do the hash , match the data you want, update the old data, write the row in a new (3rd) file etc...

For the hashing to work, the data must match from one CSV to the other (obviously), there cannot be duplicate "hashed" rows.  Rows who's data hashes the same but which has values in the other fields. Like if you had 2 rows in the same file that hash the same and then the `Close` value is different.  This would cause you trouble no matter what.

Good luck, look up some tutorials on how to process CSV files, there are plenty of them out there.

Comment: You're the man. Thanks for the effort. I started thinking in the same direction but was not able to implement. Your post helped.

Comment: Sure, I deal with CSV files all the time at my job.